# Spring Data Couchbase 2.2.0M1 raises java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/client/java/query/Query error in my SprintBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

I'm trying to use SpringDataCouchbase 2.2.0M1 (reason is N1QL support) in my SpringBoot project. I have setup everything properly (I have com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.2.2 as dependency) but when app starts it raises error as below. Its something internal, I tried older couchbase driver (2.2.0) but its the same. Does anyone can provide suitable hint?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/client/java/query/Query
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:486) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:200) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at app.VaadinBootTestApplication.main(VaadinBootTestApplication.java:16) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.couchbase.client.java.query.Query
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M1 was a milestone released at a time where the 2.2 SDK was still developer preview (so unstable as well, `2.2.0-dp`). When `2.2.0` went GA, most N1QL related classes had been renamed to have the `N1ql` prefix, for consistency.
So `Query` became `N1qlQuery` (which draws a parallel with `ViewQuery` and `SpatialViewQuery`) between 2.2.0-dp and 2.2.0.

If you don't explicitly set the dependency to the Couchbase SDK in Maven, it will pull the correct dependency (2.2.0-dp) and things should work fine. Note that you have to add a maven repository to your configuration, as described  of at the end the [blog post announcing SDC 2.0-M1](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/august/spring-data-couchbase-2.0-preview).

A lot of work has been put into Spring Data Couchbase since this first Milestone, so expect a Release Candidate soon, to be quickly followed by a GA (both should be based on the more stable and latest SDK `2.2.2`).

Thanks for trying things out, be sure to report any error you see (either in Spring's [issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH) or also on the [Couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/java-sdk), which I monitor quite closely).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That helped. I used the maven repo in my gradle config and its running!

Comment: be sure to watch for the RC and RELEASE, there's a ton of stuff that's been added since M1 ;)

Comment: Any deadline/time estimation for RC?